# Frequent TransactionException for simple query

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

Using .NET 4, LINQtoSQL, in an MVC 4 app I have just started experiencing a problem where a large amount of requests are failing. The requests seem to be failing on a very simple select from the database. There has not been an update to the servers or code base for about a week yet this problem only started this morning.
The exception is thrown (seemingly) randomly and it can happen on all pages.
The event viewer logs show the following stack trace:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: TransactionException 
    Exception message: The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction.
   at System.Transactions.TransactionState.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(InternalTransaction tx, IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification promotableSinglePhaseNotification, Transaction atomicTransaction)
   at System.Transactions.Transaction.EnlistPromotableSinglePhase(IPromotableSinglePhaseNotification promotableSinglePhaseNotification)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistNonNull(Transaction tx)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.ActivateConnection(Transaction transaction)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlConnectionManager.UseConnection(IConnectionUser user)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.get_IsSqlCe()
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.InitializeProviderMode()
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.Table`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at MYPROJECT.Services.Concrete.SettingsService.GetString(Settings settingID, String defaultValue) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\123456789\MYPROJECT.Services\Concrete\SettingsService.cs:line 40
   at MYPROJECT.Controllers.BaseController.OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\123456789\MYPROJECT\Controllers\BaseController.cs:line 37
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Wrap>b__3()
   at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap[TResult](Func`1 func)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)
```

The method in the middle which is my code is basically returning this:

```
dc.Settings.SingleOrDefault(x => x.SettingID == settingID)
```

From Googling I've read to check database connection and make sure MSDTC is running. It is, but this lead me to check the times on the server. The difference between the SQL and web servers were about 5 seconds. So I thought this might be related, but after resyncing to the domain controller I still appear to have this issue! Any help would be much appreciated.

**Update with more information**
What may be worth mentioning is that I am using NInject. So the datacontext is being handled like so:

```
Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", connectionString);
```

Then all of my services are able to reference the same data context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time-hunting was a wild goose chase. The problem was with the code. A ChangeConflictException was occurring and then subsequent requests were still being carried out in the same datacontext. I don't know how but whenever this happened it would make some requests fail completely on the simplest of database calls (as seen above). Taking out the offending code fixed the problem completely.